# Entities: Conditionals + Component members vs. O(1) Hash lookup of strategy

Tags: java, performance, architecture

I'm building a new entity system in Java. I'm wondering whether my proposed method would cause any issues, architecture-wise or performance-wise.

I want:

```
...

for (Entity entity : entities)
{
    for (Entry<String, Component> entry : entity.components.entrySet()) //collection is a Map
    {
        Component component = entry.getValue();
        component.update(deltaTime);
    }
}

...
```

vs. the undesirable alternative:

```
...


for (Entity entity : entities)
{
    if (entity.componentA != null)
        entity.componentA.update(deltaTime);

    if (entity.componentB != null)
        entity.componentB.update(deltaTime);

    //etc. for as many components as the entity has. Finite, but possibly many.
}

...
```

With the first approach, some things I've thought of in regard to the HashMap approach:

- I would avoid unecessary conditionals (non-trivial when thousands of entities are having their `update()` called);
- Read access time is O(1) on average (the only time you're likely to not get that is on a hash collision);
- `HashMap.entrySet()` must be called to iterate over the collection using for-each syntax. As I understand it from the docs, "the collection [set] is backed by the map". However this does not tell me if HashMap is internally creating the set, each time `entrySet()` is called.

Comment: Your question looks unclear to me: you mention a HashMap but there is not a HashMap in your code. Also `update` seems to be applicable to components but you call it on the entity in the first code snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version is almost certainly going to be the best design:

- More general code - covers all possible component configurations
- More succinct code and maintainable - avoid all the conditionals
- More flexible at runtime - you can dynamically change the list of components
- Fast - should be O(1) per component assuming entity.components is a sensible data structure with a good iterator

If you really care about performance and have **already profiled** that this is an important special case, you may want to consider writing a custom data structure (e.g. `ComponentList`) for entity.components, which would have an additional methods `updateAll(deltaTime)` to efficiently perform the update operation for all contained components. This has a couple of advantages:

- You can avoid the allocation of an Iterator object (which would happen if you used HashMap or ArrayList)
- You can avoid some unnecessary castings by specialising on the Component type

Answer (score 2):

> Read access time is O(1) on average (the only time you're likely to not get that is on a hash collision);

In a for each loop on the entryset, you don't need to call `map.get()`.

> However this does not tell me if HashMap is internally creating the set, each time entrySet() is called.

No it does not create a new set each time.

---

You should write the code that is the cleanest and easiest to read and maintain. If the performance is not good enough (i.e. you have profiled your application and determined that the performance issue is due to that portion of code), start optimising.

==> use a for each loop.